# Cannot view changelist as UML Class diagram in WebStorm 6.0

Tags: webstorm

This should be nice feature but corresponding button is missing in Changes tool window. I have WebStorm 6.0 under Ubuntu 12.0.10. While judging from WebStorm development roadmap the feature was added in 3 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature only works if the 'UML support' plugin is installed. Unfortunately this plugin is not available for WebStorm:(